# How to call a Macro when a named range (cell) is changed

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I am trying to call a macro named "RE_environmental" when the cell named "RE_1" is changed (i.e. they mark a X in the cell). I've tried several different variations of codes including these two and nothing is happening:

[The first code does work if I use the exact cell location and not the named cell. --> $E$62]

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Address = "RE_1" Then

     Call RE_environmental

     End If

     End Sub
```

AND

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Range("Name").Select = "RE_1" Then

     Call RE_environmental

     End If

     End Sub
```

--Thanks in Advanced and please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your first answer but make this small change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("RE_1").Address Then

        Call RE_environmental

    End If

End Sub
```

Simple syntax mistake!

Edit: To stop RE_environmental from running once the cell is empty, put the code from RE_environmental inside a do-while (not isempty(Range("RE_1"))) as long as RE_environmental is emptying "RE_1". The user won't be able to edit cells while RE_environmental is running.

Comment: Is there a way to say "End If the cell becomes empty again"?

Comment: Added answer to your question in my previous post.

Answer (score 1):

If `Target` is always single-cell range, you can use this one:

```
If Target.Address = Range("RE_1").Address Then
    Call RE_environmental
End If
```

If `Target` can be multicell range use this one:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("RE_1")) Is Nothing Then
    Call RE_environmental
End If
```

Comment: Is there a way to say "End If the cell becomes empty again"?

Comment: not sure I understand you about `End If the cell becomes empty again`? what means again? when it becomes empty first time? clarify please

Comment: If they decide they don't want to fill that specific cell anymore, is there a way to call off the macro? To tell it to take it back?

Comment: It seems far from original question, please open new qusetion, and somebody will help you:)